# Binding paper-tabs with on the post-card tutorial with little modification

Tags: javascript, polymer

I just started my first web application development using polymer. I ran into a tutorial on the polymer website, and I want to add some modifications to be able know more about this new technology. After trying to run into the tutorial, i decided to place a scaffold around the element I just made, so the paper-tabs and the post-card list are inside the scaffold's content. Then I tried to wire up the paper-tabs and post-cards again, using the favorites function introduced by the tutorial, as it turns out, I got no response. I changed also the labels of the paper-tabs but I left the name attribute unchanged.

Can you help me what's going wrong on my code?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>unquote</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <script src="../components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="../components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
  <link rel="import"
    href="../components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import"
    href="../components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import"
    href="../components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="sample-Scaffold.html">
  <style>
  html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
  }
  core-header-panel {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
  }
  core-toolbar {
    background: #03a9f4;
    color: white;
  }
  #tabs {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }
  @media (min-width: 481px) {
    #tabs {
      width: 200px;
    }
    .container {
      width: 400px;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body unresolved touch-action="auto">
<core-header-panel>
    <sample-scaffold>
    </sample-scaffold>
</core-header-panel>

  <script>
  var list = document.querySelector('post-list');
  var tabs = document.querySelector('paper-tabs');

  tabs.addEventListener('core-select', function() {
    list.show = tabs.selected;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

sampleScaffold.html

```
<link rel="import" href="/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="/components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="/components/core-item/core-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="/components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="/components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html">
<link rel="import" href="/components/core-input/core-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="/components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="/components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="post-list.html">
<polymer-element name="sample-scaffold">
  <template>
    <style>
        body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        #navheader {
        background-color: #56BA89;
        }

        .content {
        padding: 20px;
        }

        #core_field {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      }
      #tabs {
        width: 100%;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 3px 2px;
        background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
      }
    </style>
   <core-scaffold>

      <core-header-panel navigation flex>
        <core-toolbar id="navheader">
           <core-field id="core_field" icon="search" theme="core-light-theme" center horizontal layout>
            <core-icon icon="search" id="core_icon"></core-icon>
            <core-input placeholder="Device Name..." id="core_input" flex></core-input>
          </core-field>
        </core-toolbar>
        <core-menu>
            <paper-item label="Team Migration" icon="polymer" id="paper_item1" center horizontal layout></paper-item>
            <paper-item label="Team Customization" icon="polymer" id="paper_item2" center horizontal layout></paper-item>
            <paper-item label="Team Spectial Projects" icon="polymer" id="paper_item3" center horizontal layout></paper-item>
            <paper-item label="Team New Solutions" icon="polymer" id="paper_item4" center horizontal layout></paper-item>
            <paper-item label="Team SRT" icon="polymer" id="paper_item5" center horizontal layout></paper-item>
        </core-menu>
      </core-header-panel>
      <div id="div" tool>SSCOI ITEM DASHBOARD</div>
      <div class="content">
        <paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="all" valueattr="name" self-end>
          <paper-tab name="all">All devices</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab name="wires">Extension Wires</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab name="printers">Printers</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab name="pinpads">Pinpads</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab name="scanners">Scanners</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab name="favorites">Borrowed</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab name="other">Other</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
        <section id="section1" flex relative>
          <post-list show="all"></post-list>
        </section>
      </div>
</core-scaffold>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

post-card.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html">

<polymer-element name="post-card">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    .card-header {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    polyfill-next-selector { content: '.card-header h2'; }
    .card-header ::content h2 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    polyfill-next-selector { content: '.card-header img'; }
    .card-header ::content img {
      width: 70px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    core-icon-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 3px;
      right: 3px;
      fill: #636363;
    }
    :host([favorite]) core-icon-button {
      fill: #da4336;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="card-header" layout horizontal center>
      <content select="img"></content>
      <content select="h2"></content>
    </div>
    <core-icon-button
      id="favicon"
      icon="favorite"
      on-tap="{{favoriteTapped}}"></core-icon-button>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('post-card', {
    publish: {
      favorite: {
        value: false,
        reflect: true
      }
    },
    favoriteTapped: function(event, detail, sender) {
      this.favorite = !this.favorite;
      this.fire('favorite-tap');
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

post-list.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html">

<polymer-element name="post-card">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    .card-header {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    polyfill-next-selector { content: '.card-header h2'; }
    .card-header ::content h2 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    polyfill-next-selector { content: '.card-header img'; }
    .card-header ::content img {
      width: 70px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    core-icon-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 3px;
      right: 3px;
      fill: #636363;
    }
    :host([favorite]) core-icon-button {
      fill: #da4336;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="card-header" layout horizontal center>
      <content select="img"></content>
      <content select="h2"></content>
    </div>
    <core-icon-button
      id="favicon"
      icon="favorite"
      on-tap="{{favoriteTapped}}"></core-icon-button>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('post-card', {
    publish: {
      favorite: {
        value: false,
        reflect: true
      }
    },
    favoriteTapped: function(event, detail, sender) {
      this.favorite = !this.favorite;
      this.fire('favorite-tap');
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Pardon the code, I am just learning web development, the  tab in the paper-tabs, has the favorite attribute name.

Thank you so much.
Joseph Nicholas R. Alcantara

Comment: It will be easier to help you with this if you can reduce your code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also help if you copied your code into a site like jsbin.com so that answerers could see your code in action, run it with a debugger, and try various solutions.

Comment: not sure if you still have the issue.. but looks like your sampleScaffold.html should be renamed to sample-Scaffold.html, since you are importing <link rel="import" href="sample-Scaffold.html"> into index.html.... you can use google chrome to debug issues like these by going to Inspect Element>Console which will reveal issues like improper imports...